# How to implement check-chain by Rxjava/RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

i am a newer on RxJava/RxAndroid. I want to use RxJava/RxAndroid to implement the following case: First, get data from network then do some checks on the data, if any of check fails, just show error in Main Thread.

[you can see flow chart here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDWt0.png)

I try some RxJava operations but fail to find a nice way to do so.
Can someone help me on this? Many thanks!

And I write some test code about this case (using String as data), is there any more simple way?

```
Observable.just(s)
            .flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<String> apply(final String s) throws Exception {
            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
                    if(s.length() < 3){
                        e.onError(new Throwable("len"));
                    }else{
                        e.onNext(s);
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<String> apply(final String s) throws Exception {
            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
                    if(s.startsWith("a")){
                        e.onError(new Throwable("start"));
                    }else{
                        e.onNext(s);
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("get error: " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }).subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    });
```

Comment: flatMap is the thing you looking for.

Comment: thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

While you can do it with `flatMap()` it is not needed here, you can simply use `map()` for checking the data and throwing errors:

```
 Observable.just(s)
            .map(new Function<String, String>() {
                     @Override
                     public String apply(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                         if (s.length() < 3) {
                             throw new Exception("len");
                         } else if (s.startsWith("a")) {
                             throw new Exception("start");
                         }
                         return s;
                     }
                 }
            )
            .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                           @Override
                           public void accept(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                               System.out.println(s);
                           }
                       }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                           @Override
                           public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                               System.out.println("get error: " + throwable.getMessage();
                           }
                       });
```

here you checking the value emitted and simply throw the appropriate Exception according to your checks.

---

Anyhow, in your example, you don't need to create by yourself an `Observable` for emitting errors/passing thru, you can use `Observable.error()` and `Observable.just()`:

```
  .flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                    if (s.length() < 3) {
                        return Observable.error(new Exception("len"));
                    } else if (s.startsWith("a")) {
                        return Observable.error(new Exception("start"));
                    } else {
                        return Observable.just(s);
                    }
                }
            })
```

moreover, your'e not handling `onError()` at your subscriber (but on `doOnError()`) so you'll crash with `OnErrorNotImplementedException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code a bit by eliminating Observable.create() (which you should not be using anyway):

```
Observable.just(s)
        .flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<String> apply(final String s) throws Exception {
                return s.length() < 3 ? Observable.error(new Throwable("len"))
                    : Observable.just(s);
            }
        }).flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<String> apply(final String s) throws Exception {
                return s.startsWith("a") ? Observable.error(new Throwable("start"))
                    : Observable.just(s);
            }
        })
        .subscribe(...)
```

Or you can use doOnEach and Guava Preconditions:

```
Observable.just(s)
    .doOnEach(s -> {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(s >= 3, "len");
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!s.startsWith("a"), "start");
    })
    .subscribe(...)
```